# Excel SUMIF does not accepts RIGHT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get the sum of the text inside `(<number>)` like the table below

[image]

tried this formula but this does not work or throws an error

```
{=SUMIF($D1:$D7, $F1&"(*", -RIGHT($D1:$D7, 3))}
```

`RIGHT` works okay with `SUM` like this formula

```
{=SUM(-RIGHT(D1:D7,3))}
```

Comment: `SUMIF` requires the third parameter to be an address range so that won't work.  What about this:  `{=SUM((LEFT(D$1:D$7,2)=F1)*(-RIGHT(D$1:D$7,3)))}`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah works great. add this one as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUMIF` function takes the following parameters:

1. the range of cells to inspect
2. the criteria
3. the range of cells to sum

So the third parameter MUST be a range of cells.

But `-RIGHT($D1:$D7, 3)` doesn't return a range of cells - it returns an array of values.

That means `SUMIF` isn't the right tool.  Instead, make your `{=SUM(-RIGHT(D1:D7,3))}` array formula conditional by multiplying each value by one or zero based on the values in F:

`{=SUM( (LEFT(D$1:D$7,2)=F1) * (-RIGHT(D$1:D$7,3)) )}`

This is an array formula so must be entered by using Control-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter alone.  Put it in G1 and then copy it down to the other cells.